# Mongojs query finishing after rendering the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, koa

```
var list = [];
db.posts.find({}, function(err, docs){
    //console.log(docs);
    list = docs;
});

yield this.render("index", {
    posts: list
});
```

I have this function for rendering a page after pulling an array of posts from a mongo db. I know it's because of javascript being asynchronous, but I can't seem to get the order right (get array, then render) and the solutions I've seen don't seem to mingle well with koa. How would I code this in order to get the array before the page is rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what mongodb library you are using, but it seems the library only supports callbacks.

To program in the `synchronous` style using `yield` you must use functions that return promises, thunks, generators etc (as you saw in error message).

You can either find a mongodb library that supports promises (mongoosejs i think) or you can wrap the library you are using.

Here are a couple examples of converting your library to a workable format

```
// Manually change callback to promise returning function
var Promise = require('bluebird');
function find(criteria){
    var deffered, list;
    deffered = Promise.defer();
    db.posts.find(criteria, function(err, results){
        if(err){
            deffered.reject(err);
        }
        else{
            deffered.resolve(result);
        }
    }
    return deffered.promise;
}
// in your returning function do something like this
list = yield find({});
this.body = yield render('sometemplate', {posts: list});



// Thunk based solution
var thunkify = require('thunkify');
db.posts.find = thunkify(db.posts.find);
// now db.posts.find() returns a thunk which is yieldable
list = yield db.posts.find({});
this.body = yield render('sometemplate', {posts: list});
```

Comment: I was using mongojs, but either way the thunkify method worked! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
var list = yield db.posts.find({}).toArray();
console.log(list);
yield this.render("index", {posts: list});
```

Comment: It's giving me `TypeError: You may only yield a function, promise, generator, array, or object, but the following object was passed: "[object Object]"`. I believe this is because find() returns a cursor (stream?), but I do not know how to read from it.

Comment: You could do `list = yield db.posts.find({}).toArray();`